# Click on formula cell that uses match and index to link / jump to source cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that is being used to let employees vote on a "wishlist" of items to improve about our software. ***I would like to figure out how to click on the "Top Three wishes" issue number and have it link to the issue in the main table.*** For instance, if someone wanted to see what the actual description of the top wish, 44, was, they would click on the 44 in the Issue# column and it would take them to row 44 in the worksheet. Right now, double clicking will highlight the entire "Average" column in the main table.

The worksheet looks as follows:

```
                                       "G"   Top three wishes
                                             Issue #    Average
                                        1    44         5.0
                                        2    2          4.7
                                        3    9          4.5

Number    Description                    Emp1     Emp2    EmpN     Average
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         Group Reports by Date          3        4       4        3.7
2         User Activity Journaling       5        5       4        4.7
etc......
```

The main table "Average" column has a forumla of:

```
=AVERAGE(C21:L21)
```

Where rows C-L are all the employee votes.

The Top three wishes "Average" column has a formula of:

```
=LARGE($M$9:$M$82, G2)
```

Where G2 is a hidden cell that references what "Top three" number this refers to. For instance, if G2 held "2", it would show the second highest rated wish. G1 would then hold "1", the most highly rated wish.

The Top three wishes "Issue #" column has a formula of:

```
=INDEX($A$9:$A$82,MATCH(I2,$M$9:$M$82,0))
```

Where "I" is the top three wishes "Average" column.

I believe that is all the pertinent information. Let me know if I left anything out, and thanks for your time!

Comment: You clearly have a formula that retrieves the **44**.  Can you place in a nearby cell a formula that holds the *address* of the cell containing the **44** ??

Comment: Oh, that's an idea/workaround. Let me work on that for a while until a more all in one solution is found :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to adapt this, but if not I will delete this answer.  It shows a way to marry a lookup formula to a hyperlink.  Say our data is like:

[image]

 That is name,score,description.
We want to lookup Darth Vader's score and insert a hyperlink to the description.  In **A1** we put `Darth Vader` and in **A2** we enter the lookup formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,H1:J22,2,FALSE)
```

which displays the **20**.  Now we know that Darth Vader is in the 13th row and that `=MATCH(A1,H:H,0)`  will give us that 13 and we use this formula within the hyperlink.  So in **A3** we enter:

```
=HYPERLINK("#J" & MATCH(A1,H:H,0),A1)
```

**A3** will now contain a hyperlink to Darth Vader's description:

[image]